# Padding found in the Default time bar and android of exoplayer

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

Here is the implementation of the Default time bar where I have customized to add segments

**XML**

```
 <com.sampleapp.androidapp.kotlin.util.exoplayer.SampleAppDefaultTimeBar
                android:id="@id/exo_progress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:bar_height="2dp"
                app:buffered_color="@color/gb_seek_bar_buffer"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:played_color="@color/gb_seek_bar_played"
                app:scrubber_color="@color/gb_seek_bar_played"
                app:unplayed_color="@color/gb_seek_bar_unplayed" />
```

**Code**

```
class SampleAppDefaultTimeBar : DefaultTimeBar {

    companion object {
        const val DIVIDER_WIDTH = 5F
        const val PROGRESS_LEFT_RIGHT_PADDING = 32F
    }

    // List of points for creating sections
    var indicatorPositions: List<Float> = arrayListOf()
    var enableSegmentsForPlayer: Boolean = false
    //var indicatorPositions: List<Float> = listOf(0.13F, 0.34F, 0.57F, 0.85F, 0.92F)

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(context,
        attrs, defStyle)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    private val paintIndicator = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
        color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        drawProgressDivider(canvas)
    }

    private fun drawProgressDivider(canvas: Canvas) {
        if(enableSegmentsForPlayer){
            // Only if the segments are enabled - Draw the segments
            indicatorPositions.forEach {
                val barPositionCenter = it * width()
                val barPositionLeft = barPositionCenter - DIVIDER_WIDTH
                val barPositionRight = barPositionCenter + DIVIDER_WIDTH

                drawOnCanvas(canvas, paintIndicator, barPositionLeft, barPositionRight)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun width(): Float {
        return measuredWidth.toFloat()
    }

    private fun drawOnCanvas(canvas: Canvas, paint:Paint, progressLeft: Float, progressRight: Float) {
        //val barTop = (measuredHeight - barHeight) / 2
        //val barBottom = (measuredHeight + barHeight) / 2
        val progressTop = height / 1.8 - minimumHeight / 2
        val progressBottom = progressTop / 1.3 + minimumHeight / 2

        val barRect = RectF(progressLeft, progressTop.toFloat(),
            progressRight, progressBottom.toFloat())
        canvas.drawRoundRect(barRect, 50F, 50F, paint)
    }

}
```

**Output**

[image]

- As seen in the image above there is padding at the beginning and end of
  the bar if the points are found to be at the very begining.
- It's the space for the thumb
- How to remove that Padding

Comment: @Devarth Did anyone find any solution for the same? facing the same issue.

Comment: @krupaparekh .. I added a seek bar drawable behind the view as a workaround ... it was not perfect solution but it was okay

Comment: @Devarth How you managed seekbar to seek? Doesn't seekbar and `DefaultTimeBar` getting conflicted? It would be great if you provide some code insides if possible

Comment: @krupaparekh ... Check this if it helps: https://medium.com/@devrath.dev595/creating-a-custom-segmented-seek-bar-like-youtube-624b4ffc9f25
Not sure if this is exact thing you are looking for, Hope it helps in your usecase

Comment: @Devarth Thanks for the help! but my requirements are different. I don't need a segmented view but just want to remove extra padding from start and end.

Comment: @krupaparekh ... Observe the start and end of the seek to bar it's not totally transparent, instead it's closer to the color of seek bar. 
.
It's not possible to remove the padding in the default one given, Unless you extend and build your own implementation

Comment: @Devarth Yes, I get to know it is not possible to remove that padding. Have you tried to make your own seek bar not `DefaultTimeBar` then manage seeking like exoplayer?

Comment: @krupaparekh ... No It was not required in my case since I gave segments at the first and end of the seek bar.

Answer (score 0):

The padding on either side of the DefaultTimeBar is added to allow space for the scrubber and still be centered. [See this answer on github](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4775#issuecomment-418691588). If you don't want the scrubber you can set the scrubber size to 0dp on all states and the timebar will extend to the bounds of the view.

An example with the latest version of the `DefaultTimeBar` using the Jetpack Media3 library.

```
 <androidx.media3.ui.DefaultTimeBar
    android:id="@+id/exo_progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    app:touch_target_height="0dp"
    app:scrubber_color="@android:color/transparent"
    app:scrubber_disabled_size="0dp"
    app:scrubber_dragged_size="0dp"
    app:scrubber_enabled_size="0dp"
 />
```